# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) Can't get data from database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT playerid, score FROM table ORDER BY playerid");
$result = mysqli_connect->query($query);
```

Comment: you should pass database parameter to `mysqli_connect` and assign to the variable. then call it like as you mentioned in the question

refer this : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php Please read the document first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code.

First is you are not using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) correctly.

Next is the `FROM table` section of your SQL statement. `table` in most SQL languages is a reserved word and will give you errors. If `table` was supposed to be substituted for something else then it goes back to the misuse of `sprintf()`

I hope this helps.